# Creating stored procedure on IBM DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I've created stored procedures before using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), but doing this for an IBM DB2 database is causing problems.

My SQL for creating the stored procedure is:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetMonthModelCount (in dtStart varchar(6), in dtEnd varchar(6))
    RESULT SETS 1
    LANGUAGE SQL
-- dtStart and dtEnd must be dates of the format YYYYMM
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT DAMDLN, Count(*)
    FROM TEST_DATA.DLRINVAPF
    WHERE DASTAT='RT' AND DADTRS BETWEEN SUBSTR(dtStart, 1, 6) AND SUBSTR(dtEnd, 1, 6);
END
```

IBM Data Studio looks like this:

[image: IBM Data Studio screenshot]

As you can see above, when it fails, it tells me `INTO clause missing from embedded statement.`

Something is different than what I am used to with SSMS. I want to return a table of data. How would I modify my statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a cursor from your stored procedure to return the result set of the query by using `DECLARE <variable> CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR <statement>` and `OPEN <variable>`.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetMonthModelCount (in dtStart varchar(6), in dtEnd varchar(6))
    RESULT SETS 1
    LANGUAGE SQL
-- dtStart and dtEnd must be dates of the format YYYYMM
BEGIN
    DECLARE c CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
        SELECT DAMDLN, Count(*) AS month_model_count
        FROM TEST_DATA.DLRINVAPF
        WHERE DASTAT='RT' 
            AND DADTRS BETWEEN SUBSTR(dtStart, 1, 6) AND SUBSTR(dtEnd, 1, 6)
        GROUP BY DAMDLN;
   
    OPEN c;
END
```

The `COUNT` in DB2 will require a `GROUP BY` to run and the `DISTINCT` can be dropped.

Comment: Thanks! DB2 has weird rules. Everything seems to have short names. How do I know if my variable names or stored procedure name is acceptable? Is `sp_GetMonthModelCount` too long?

Comment: @jp2code Stored procedure names can be up to 128 characters, same for column and table names. [DB2's limits](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=sql-xml-limits) are fairly generous.

Comment: @jp2code Actually Db2 follows closely to the SQL Standards.  It's MSSQL that's odd.

Comment: @Charles - all I was missing was the cursor. It doesn't even play a role in any of the code, so I'm not sure why the SQL Standard would require it.

Comment: @jp2code Now that I've had coffee, I recall  that the standards don't actually cover SQL Procedure Language (PL).   A cursor is just the DB side name for an open result set.  MS SQL uses them to, they are simply implicit in it's PL.

Comment: @Charles - how do I call this stored procedure? `exec sp_Name` does not work. `call sp_Name` gives Error 204.

Comment: @Charles - never mind! I got it! `call TEST_DATA.sp_Name` works like a charm! :)